# Why is Benten the way she is?

Tags: the-eccentric-family

I don't really understand her. She's human, but she can fly (I guess Akadama-sensei taught her how to fly when he kidnapped her and raised her as a Tengu) but then, she's kinda left him alone.

And then she joins Friday Fellows, and eats tank hot pot. But she knows who and what this tanuki is. And later, she goes back to Akadama-sensei.

So,

- What exactly is her purpose?
- What's the reason behind this behavior of hers?
- Is she the antagonist or the protagonist in the series?

Comment: Just to fill in a bit of details: Benten was kidnapped by Akadama-sensei, and raised by him to be a tengu. That's why she can fly. (How she, starting as a human rather than a tengu, can learn how to fly is not really explained, though).

Comment: She's a player.

Comment: afaik, it just happened that friday fellows has a custom where the new member must prepare a tanuki for hotpot. it's just her playful and unpredictable nature to do something she wants whenever she wishes. pretty sure she's quite different from japan's version of benten one of the gods of fortune