# Is there something special about Benten?

Tags: the-eccentric-family

Near to the end we learn that the reason why Souichirō stopped seeing Akadama-sensei was because whenever Benten was around he could keep his transformation and revert back to being a Tanuki.

In the final episode when the dividing wall between the Tanuki's attending the Trick Miester Election and the Friday Club is knocked down some of the Tanuki instantly transform. but it isn't until Benten turns up that every other Tanuki reverts back to their tanuki form.

Added to the fact that Benten was an ordinary girl from the countryside until Akadama-sensei abducted her and taught her how to fly is Benten really just some ordinary girl?

Comment: somewhat related http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13979/why-is-benten-the-way-she-is